# Posting/submitting multiple forms in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms on a page (one is being grabbed by AJAX).  I need them both to be posted, so I serialize the second one and send it in a post using jQuery before submitting the first one.  However, only the first form appears to be getting posted.  The odd thing is though, if I put an alert after the serialized post it works as expected.  What exactly is my problem here?

```
$("#submit").livequery('click', function() {
    var form = $("#second_form");
    var action = form.attr("action");
    var serialized_form = form.serialize();
    $.post(action, serialized_form);

    //alert('test');

    $("#first_form").submit();

    return false;
});
```

Is there any better way to post two forms and then redirect to a new page on a button press?  I tried posting both of them using the method above and then using window.location to change pages but I had a similar problem.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try submitting "first_form" in a callback from the post of "second_form".  I believe that the submit of "first_form" is unloading the page which causes the second post to be aborted.  Doing the post of "first_form" in the callback from "second_form" will ensure that the initial post is complete before the second post begins.

```
$("#submit").livequery('click', function() {
    var form = $("#second_form");
    var action = form.attr("action");
    var serialized_form = form.serialize();
    $.post(action, serialized_form, submit_first);
});

function submit_first(val) {
   $("#first_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much - I didn't realize that submitting unloaded the page. :D