# How do I make a form that can log into two places at the same time?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, simultaneous

How do I make a form that can log into two places simultaneously?

http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/3127/calendarlogin.jpg
http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1567/joomlalogin.jpg

These two login forms are for a calendar and a joomla site. They work separately. They're in the same public_html directory. The login forms submit to two separate index.php files. I would like it if I could get a user to login to both separately, by submitting once to a form. How can I do that. I'm thinking of using an intermediate php file that links to the two in the form but I can't figure out how to.

Both the username and password fields for both forms use the same values for all users.

edit: oh wow, I thought there might be a simple solution. I've tried modifying login functions. Hasn't quite worked. The idea of integrating the calendar with joomla seems a bit hard. This would be the best way to work with things like session timeouts though.

No more answers please, I think I'm gonna spend a bit more time trying stuff before I reask the question.

edit: the problem is that I don't want to have people have to log in twice to access both areas of the site.

Comment: I don't see any problem here...

Comment: This should not be your aim, your aim should be to get both systems to integrate with one user table. This should especially be possible with an extensible piece of software like Joomla!

Comment: I would think JQuery would be able to do it.  Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315912/posting-submitting-multiple-forms-in-jquery.

Comment: As @Dunhamzzz said, I would say that I'm sure there are plenty of Joomla extensions regarding calendars and events. You can take a look [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/1625).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid doing this but for the sake of an academic exercise this is the answer.

```
<?php
$logged_in = false;
$site1_url = 'http://google.com';
$site2_url = 'http://redis.io';

if(array_key_exists('username', $_POST)
        and array_key_exists('password', $_POST)) {

    // Assume the text input fields are named the same in all three forms
    $fields = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $_POST['password'],
    );

    // Access the first site
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site1_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $output1 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Access the second site
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site2_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $output2 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(strpos($output1, 'Logged In') and
            strpos($output2, 'Signed In')) {
        // set logged_in to true only when the appropriate strings are found
        // in the pages we have just posted onto so that we know that the logins
        // were actually successful.
        $logged_in = true;
    }
}
if(false === $logged_in):
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>You are now logged into the website.</p>
    <p>To access the sites try:</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php htmlentities($site1_url); ?>"><?php htmlentities($site1_url); ?></a>
        <li><a href="<?php htmlentities($site2_url); ?>"><?php htmlentities($site2_url); ?></a>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```